# AngularJS input change reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, search, input

I have a simple search box. When the input box is not empty a delete button shows up to remove the text inside the box. After that the button should disappear again until i type something in the box again.

When i manually remove the text the delete box is disappearing, but when i press the delete button its not working.
 Do i have to use .length? I was using .value before like that:
 `if ($(".form-control").value == '' || $(".form-control").value == $(".form-control").defaultValue) {`

Thanks in advance.

a = $scope

```
    a.change = function () {
        a.limit = 6;

        var x = a.search;
        if (x.length == '') {


            $(".form-inline").removeClass("isset");
        } else {
            $(".form-inline").addClass("isset");
        }
    };


    a.clearSearch = function () {
        a.search = "";
        a.limit = 6;
    };
```

html part:

```
<input type="search" ng-change="change()" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Labor durchsuchen...">

<div class="icon-close" ng-click="clearSearch()"></div>
```

Comment: why are you using jquery in angular?

Comment: so you can see which div's i mean

Comment: It's not advisable to mix Jquery code in with angularjs when there are native angularjs ways to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ng-class** for that what you are doing with JQuery:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.formData = {};
 $scope.change = function () {
       //do anything here
    };


   $scope.clearSearch = function () {
        $scope.formData.search = "";
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
<input type="search" ng-class="(formData.search != undefined && formData.search)?'isset':''" ng-change="change()" ng-model="formData.search" class="form-control" placeholder="Labor durchsuchen...">

<div class="icon-close" ng-click="clearSearch()"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to drop the jQuery code and just use

```
<div class="icon-close" ng-click="clearSearch()" ng-show="search.length===0"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to trigger your `a.change` function inside `a.cleanSearch` to check again if something is typed or not.

```
a.clearSearch = function () {
  a.search = "";
  a.limit = 6;
  a.change()
};
```